# How to retrieve image from sql server

Tags: java, sql-server, mime

I have stored images in sql server database . I need to fetch them and send them via email. Is there any way to store the image in a variable and send that in email body.

Here is code for uploading image from system path

```
public class ImageInsert {

 private static java.sql.Date getCurrentDate() {
        java.util.Date today = new java.util.Date();
        return new java.sql.Date(today.getTime());
    }
 public void insertImage() {
// declare a connection by using Connection interface 
Connection connection = null;
/* Create string of connection url within specified format with machine 
name, port number and database name. Here machine name id localhost 
and database name is Test. */
String connectionURL = "jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=Test";
/*declare a resultSet that works as a table resulted by execute a specified 
sql query. */
ResultSet rs = null;
// Declare prepare statement.
PreparedStatement psmnt = null;
// declare FileInputStream object to store binary stream of given image.
FileInputStream fis;
try {
    // Load JDBC driver "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
    /* Create a connection by using getConnection() method that takes 
    parameters of string type connection url, user name and password to 
    connect to database. */
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "sa", "$arat0ga~");
    // create a file object for image by specifying full path of image as parameter.
    File media = new File("C:/HBD.jpg");
    /* prepareStatement() is used for create statement object that is 
    used for sending sql statements to the specified database. */
    psmnt = connection.prepareStatement("insert into WishEmail(filename, media, date ) " + "values(?,?,?)");
    psmnt.setString(1, "Happy Birthday");
    psmnt.setDate(3, getCurrentDate());
    fis = new FileInputStream(media);
    psmnt.setBinaryStream(2, (InputStream) fis, (int)(media.length()));
    /* executeUpdate() method execute specified sql query. Here this query 
    insert data and image from specified address. */
    int s = psmnt.executeUpdate();
    if (s > 0) {
        System.out.println("Uploaded successfully !");
    } else {
        System.out.println("unsucessfull to upload image.");
    }
}
// catch if found any exception during rum time.
catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println("Found some error : " + ex);
} finally {
    //finally block used to close resources
      try{
         if(psmnt!=null)
            connection.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
      }// do nothing
      try{
         if(connection!=null)
            connection.close();
      }catch(SQLException se){
         se.printStackTrace();
      }//end finally try

}
 }
```

It is stored in db in binary format
Here is code for inserting into db

```
public class DB {

public DB() {}

public Connection dbConnect(String db_connect_string,
   String db_userid, String db_password)
{
        try
        {
                Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
                Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                  db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);

                System.out.println("connected");
                return conn;

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return null;
        }
}

public void insertImage(Connection conn,String img)
{
        int len;
        String query;
        PreparedStatement pstmt;

        try
        {
                File file = new File(img);
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                len = (int)file.length();

                query = ("insert into WishEmail VALUES(?,?,?)");
                pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                pstmt.setString(1,file.getName());
                pstmt.setInt(2, len);

                // Method used to insert a stream of bytes
                pstmt.setBinaryStream(3, fis, len); 
                pstmt.executeUpdate();

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }
}

public void getImageData(Connection conn)
{

         byte[] fileBytes;
         String query;
         try
         {
                 query = "select image from WishEmail";
                 Statement state = conn.createStatement();
                 ResultSet rs = state.executeQuery(query);
                 if (rs.next())
                {
                          fileBytes = rs.getBytes(1);
                          OutputStream targetFile=  
                          new FileOutputStream(
                               "C:/DEF.jpg");

                          targetFile.write(fileBytes);

                          targetFile.close();
                }        

         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
                 e.printStackTrace();
         }
}
```

Here is code for sending email

```
public class Mail {



public void sendEmail() throws IOException
{

    GetPropsValue props = new GetPropsValue();
    props.getPropValues();
    String replyTo= props.toAddress1;
    String mailFrom = props.fromAddress1;
    String smtpHost = props.smtpHost1;
    //Get the session object  
      Properties properties = System.getProperties(); 

      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", smtpHost);
      properties.setProperty("replyTo", replyTo); 
      properties.setProperty("mailFrom",mailFrom); 
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);  

      generateAndSendEmail(
                session,
                replyTo,
                mailFrom,
                "Email for Birthday Wishes",
                "Greetings, <br><br>Happy Birthday.");

}

public static void generateAndSendEmail(Session session, String toEmail,String mailFrom, String subject, String body) { 

    //compose the message  
      try{  
          System.out.println("\n ===> generateAndSendEmail() starts..");
          MimeMessage mime1 = new MimeMessage(session);
          mime1.addHeader("Content-type", "text/HTML; charset=UTF-8");
            mime1.addHeader("format", "flowed");
            mime1.addHeader("Content-Transfer-Encoding", "8bit");
            mime1.setFrom(new InternetAddress(mailFrom,toEmail));
            mime1.setSubject(subject, "UTF-8");
            mime1.setSentDate(new Date());
            mime1.setRecipients(Message.RecipientType.TO,InternetAddress.parse(toEmail, false));
         // Create the message body part
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent(body, "text/html");

            // Create a multipart message for attachment
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

         // Valid file location
            String filename = "C:/ABC.jpg";
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
            // Trick is to add the content-id header here
            messageBodyPart.setHeader("Content-ID", "image_id");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            System.out.println("\n ===> third part for displaying image in the email body..");
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            messageBodyPart.setContent("<br><h3>Happy Birthday</h3>"
                    + "<img src='cid:image_id'>", "text/html");
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
            mime1.setContent(multipart);
            messageBodyPart.setContent("<br><h3>Regards</h3>", "text/html");

            System.out.println("\n ===> Finally Send message..");

            // Finally Send message
            Transport.send(mime1);

            System.out
                    .println("\n ===> Email Sent Successfully With Image Attachment. Check your email now..");
            System.out.println("\n ===> generateAndSendEmail() ends..");

        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


}
```

Comment: What are you asking about? SQL storage or email attachments?

Comment: You could save the JPG's data into Base64 in the SQL table, or you could also save the file on the server and save the path to the file in the table.

Comment: storing images in relational db is generally a bad idea. file on disk or nosql storage like mongo should work better. what exactly do you want to know?

Comment: I need to store email and dob in a database and then need to send email with an image wishing them on their birthday. Images should be on database .

Comment: Not sure why are so adamant the images have to stored in sql. As several have already mentioned this is generally not a good approach. Maybe FILESTREAM is an option? If you store the image in a varbinary(max) column you will have to first materialize the bytes as a file, then attach it to the email.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am just trying to fetch from database though its a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

convert image into BASE64 string using the below code.

```
   byte[] encodedBytes = null;
      String contents = "";
      Scanner scanner = null;
      StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
      String NL = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        try {
            encodedBytes = new Base64().encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(new File(fFileName)));
            contents = new String(encodedBytes);
        }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
        }
        return "data:image/png;base64,"+contents;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Short term i am telling you!!!!
First of all create table and then add column image url and save image url on this and when you fetch details fetch it also and set on Label

Comment: I cannot store the url, since images should be uploaded to the database and then email should pick those images and send email.